# Android : Unable to decode stream/File not found error

Tags: java, file, bitmap, filenotfoundexception

So i am having trouble with saving my file to the folder. I keep getting

> "E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /File:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Pix/JPG_2016-03-15
>   02:57:56.264-0400-1837017846.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or
>   directory)" error.

I already have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission` added so I know it's not that.

Anyways here's my code for the file and the picture callback

```
public Bitmap createFile() throws IOException {
        String mCurrentPhotoPath;
        File image;
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Pix");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.e("Pix", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPG_" + timeStamp;
        image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", mediaStorageDir);
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "File:" + image.getAbsoluteFile();
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        Log.d(TAG, "bitmap decoded :(" + bitmap);

        return bitmap;
    }

public Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Bitmap pictureFile = null;
            try {
                pictureFile = createFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(pictureFile));
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found" + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file" + e.getMessage());
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    };
```

Any help or direction to find the answer is greatly appricated! thanks!